# How do I use a text file as input in Python?

Tags: python, linux, bash, enumeration

This may seem like a simple question but this is the first time I have touched Python so bear with me.

I created a simple bash script to do some SMTP enumeration and have been trying to convert it into a Python script. The bash script was:
[image]

And so far the Python script I have is this:

[image]

But right now, I have to type in each username individually once and the script closes. I have created a simple text file with a bunch of possible usernames and want to be able to use all the usernames in that file instead of typing them in individually one by one but am not sure on how to do that.

Comment: Copy the contents of those pictures **as text**, into the question itself!

Comment: The python script, as reported, will raise a `NameError: name 's' is not defined`

Comment: You might want to spend some time in [The Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files).

Answer (score 2):

```
with open('users.txt') as users:
    for user in users:
        s.send(...)
```

Comment: I have no experience dealing with a SMPT server, but is it OK to send them a string that's newline terminated?